# How do I change position of significance bars to match fill comparisons?

Tags: r, ggplot2, position, ggpubr

I am currently using ggpubr to add significance comparisons to my ggplot2 boxplots. There are two things I want to do that I can't seem to do.

1) My boxplot currently has two comparisons per factor. I want to be able to place significance bars for each comparison I want, with the 1st group of comparisons above the boxplot and the 2nd group of comparisons below the boxplot. Currently both are stacked on top of each other on top of the boxplot as shown in the image.

2) I want to shift the significance bars to the right or left to match the position of the boxes.

I tried using position_dodge like I'm used to doing in ggplot but it doesn't seem to work here. I'm not really sure how to change the coordinates within the ggpubr system. If this doesn't work I guess I'll resort to doing manual lines and text in ggplot2...

```r
ggplot(df.plot.melt, aes(x = as.factor(TYPE), y = value, fill = variable)) +
  geom_boxplot() + theme_bw() + 
  stat_compare_means(comparisons = list(c("1", "NA"), c("2", "NA")), 
      position = position_dodge(height = 2, width = -0.2)) +
  stat_compare_means(comparisons = 
     list(c("1", "3"), c("1", "NA"), c("2", "3"), c("2", "NA")), 
     position = position_dodge(height = -2, width = 0.2))
```

[image: boxplot]

Comment: Apparently `ggpubr`'s  `stat_compare_means` [lets you specify](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/ggpubr/versions/0.1.8/topics/stat_compare_means) where you want them with `aes()`, maybe play around with x and y in `aes(x=2,y=3)`?